# Error Creating Temp Tables Using AWS SDK redshift connection [awswrangler]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-sdk

I'm using awswrangler for Pandas to pull redshift data using in a notebook. The queries I'm working with run several SQL temp tables before the final selection. But I'm running into this error:

`ProgrammingError: {'S': 'ERROR', 'C': '42601', 'M': 'cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement', 'F': '../src/pg/src/backend/tcop/postgres.c', 'L': '3916', 'R': 'exec_parse_message'}`

For example here's a simplification of temp table and the overall structure of the code:

```
import awswrangler as wr

con = wr.redshift.connect('database connection')


query = """create temp table snapshot as  (

    select * from table1
    
    );

select * 
from snapshot;""""""


wr.redshift.read_sql_query(query, con)
```

Can I resolve this? The issue is the connection made by awswrangler. A query like this is doable using an engine using sqlalchemy.